# Error in adding dependency for firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm facing this issue since yesterday... I am adding:

```
//Add Library
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.2'
```

and the only code left for the app is:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
```

As soon as I'm adding this I'm getting an error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.1.0) from [com.android.support:design:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.0.1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

I've already tried compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0' but no use.

Need some help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try changing the ui dependency and support version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this link](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#upgrading-dependencies) in the **firebase UI** readme:

> If you would like to **use a newer version of one of FirebaseUI's transitive dependencies**, such as Firebase, Play services, or the Android support libraries, **you need to add explicit compile declarations** in your `build.gradle` for all of FirebaseUI's dependencies at the version you want to use.

For example if you want to use Play services/Firebase version `FOO` and support libraries version `BAR` add the following extra lines for each FirebaseUI module you're using:

**Auth:**

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$FOO"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$FOO"

compile "com.android.support:design:$BAR"
compile "com.android.support:customtabs:$BAR"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$BAR"
```

Then in your case you have to use:

```
compile "com.android.support:design:26.1.0"
compile "com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
```

**When your FirebasuUi Version is 2.3.0, your Firebase/Play Services Version must be 11.0.4**

**Your Library**

```
//Add Library
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0' //--->Same to your buildToolVersion
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.2.0'  //--->2.3.0
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.2' //--->11.0.4
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.2' //--->11.0.4
```

**Note**

Until now, the latest buildToolVersion is 26.0.2 .

Answer (score 0):

I follow this suggestion:

> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml

So, adding this meta-data to my manifest resolve my problem:

```
<meta-data
    tools:replace="android:value"
    android:name="android.support.VERSION"
    android:value="26.1.0" />
```