# Android, Firebase: Manifest merger failed

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, firebaseui

I use information from  official documentation: [Compatibility with Firebase / Google Play Services Libraries](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries)

So here my **app/build.gradle**:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firebase"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

But when I try to build I get error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
    is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Have you tried to do what the message said?

Comment: Of caurse: but I get error: tools:replace specified at line:6 for attribute android:value, but no new value specified

Comment: This help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267746/error-in-adding-dependency-for-firebase-ui-auth2-3-0